# What and why is "TypeError: Required argument 'layout' (pos 2) not found" error in Python??

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.1

Can I know why the error occurs and also i need help getting to run this project ??

**When I type**

```
python mlp_training.py
```

**The ERROR I GET**

```
Loading training data...
(0, 38400)
(0, 4)
Loading image duration: 0.000199834
Training MLP ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mlp_training.py", line 49, in <module>
    num_iter = model.train((train, ( train_labels ), ( params )))
TypeError: Required argument 'layout' (pos 2) not found
```

THE CODE

```
__author__ = 'zhengwang'

import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

print 'Loading training data...'
e0 = cv2.getTickCount()

# load training data
image_array = np.zeros((1, 38400))
label_array = np.zeros((1, 4), 'float')
training_data = glob.glob('training_data/*.npz')

for single_npz in training_data:
 with np.load(single_npz) as data:
    print data.files
    train_temp = data['train']
    train_labels_temp = data['train_labels']
    print train_temp.shape
    print train_labels_temp.shape
 image_array = np.vstack((image_array, train_temp))
 label_array = np.vstack((label_array, train_labels_temp))

train = image_array[1:, :]
train_labels = label_array[1:, :]
print train.shape
print train_labels.shape

e00 = cv2.getTickCount()
time0 = (e00 - e0)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
print 'Loading image duration:', time0

# set start time
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

# create MLP
layer_sizes = np.int32([38400, 32, 4])
model = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_create()
model.setLayerSizes(layer_sizes)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS, 500, 0.0001)
criteria2 = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 100, 0.001)
params = dict(term_crit = criteria,
           train_method = cv2.ml.ANN_MLP_BACKPROP,
           bp_dw_scale = 0.001,
           bp_moment_scale = 0.0 )

print 'Training MLP ...'
num_iter = model.train((train, ( train_labels ), ( params )))

# set end time
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
time = (e2 - e1)/cv2.getTickFrequency()
print 'Training duration:', time

# save param
model.save('mlp_xml/mlp.xml')

print 'Ran for %d iterations' % num_iter

ret, resp = model.predict(train)
prediction = resp.argmax(-1)
print 'Prediction:', prediction
true_labels = train_labels.argmax(-1)
print 'True labels:', true_labels

print 'Testing...'
train_rate = np.mean(prediction == true_labels)
print 'Train rate: %f:' % (train_rate*100)
```

I am using python. I am using OpenCV 3.2.0. The language i am learning is C++ but for a project i am doing in python. I'm sorry.

The link to the GitHub page is
https://github.com/hamuchiwa/AutoRCCar

ALL CREDITS OF CODE TO ITS OWNER. I have simply copied the code and modified it here and there to fill my needs.

PLEASE FEEL FREE TO ASK ANY QUESTIONS I REALLY NEED IT SOLVED

My System:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: `model.train()` needs 2 arguments. You have provided only 1 i.e a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are providing wrong amount of arguments to the `train` method of ANN_MLP class of OpenCV. It requires at least 3. <strike>Here are the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html#cvann-mlp-train)</strike> Please check the edit.

The problem itself is on this line:

```
print 'Training MLP ...'
num_iter = model.train((train, ( train_labels ), ( params )))
```

You're sending one tuple into it. (Tuples in python look like this: `(1,2,3)`)
You can try to change it to look like this:

```
print 'Training MLP ...'
num_iter = model.train(train, train_labels, params)
```

But I somehow doubt this would be the only fix needed to make it work.

EDIT: I wrongly looked to the docs for the older version. Looks like you're trying to use one of the `train` overloaded methods that require one argument from the new OpenCV, but python bindings might be off, and somehow python thinks you're trying to use the [2/3] `train` method from [these docs](http://www.docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/db/d7d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1StatModel.html#af96a0e04f1677a835cc25263c7db3c0c)

Comment: Yes I did make the change as u suggested but i then receive this error   
<br/>
   ` Loading training data...
    (0, 38400)
    (0, 4)
    Loading image duration: 0.000199966
    Training MLP ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "mlp_training.py", line 49, in <module>
        num_iter = model.train(train, train_labels, params)
    TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`
 <br/>
now what do i do??

Comment: @CarlMccarry Sadly, I think, there is no silver bullet for your problem, you'll need to read OpenCV python bindings source to understand what's going on, more or less. So I think you'll have to learn python a bit more to get your project done